# C# Manually triggered MouseDown fails to trigger MouseUp

Tags: c#, events

Let's say I have a created a Form class and a CustomControl class.

On my Form I have two instances of the CustomControl, and a Panel.

Panel has 4 event handlers: MouseEnter (to give a different cursor), MouseLeave (to reset the cursor), MouseDown (to start the dragging thread), and MouseUp (to kill the dragging thread and do post-drag logic).

I can drag the Panel onto the CustomControl. When I do this, the code in Form detects what I have done and deletes Panel from Form.Controls, passes some meta-information to CustomControl, which then creates a Panel on itself.

Basically, it is a hand-over. The Panel object now belongs to the CustomControl.
*(This is necessary. It's complicated to explain why, but imagine the custom control has something like scrollbars, and it's necessary for the Panel to belong to the CustomControl so that it will scroll with the CustomControl.)*

Now, when I click down on the Panel in the CustomControl, the Panel's MouseDown is triggered, it gets deleted from CustomControl.Controls and sends some meta-information back to the Parent (the Form), which then re-creates the Panel as it was at the start - however *already in a dragging state* so that the user can re-position the Panel onto the second CustomControl, or perhaps put it back onto the Form. The function which creates the Panel when the Form is first initialised is exactly the same function which creates it now.

However, the Panel's MouseDown has not been triggered. The mouse *is* down, but the event is not firing because the mouse was already down when it was created. So, I manually call the MouseDown handler in the function in Form which accepts the meta-information from CustomControl.

Unfortunately, this only half-works. The MouseUp handler isn't firing. I can pick up the Panel off the CustomControl and drag it around on the Form as expected, but when I release the mouse, the Panel is stuck to the cursor.

I'm not really sure how to get around this?

An ideal solution would be for, when the meta-information is passed back to Form and the new Panel is created, the MouseDown event to somehow fire naturally as though the user had just clicked down on the Panel.

Comment: Just because you call the Mousedown event, doesn't mean that the panel thinks that the mouse has been pressed.  Look into actually sending the windows message for mousedown to the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are creating a new instance of Panel when you move it from CustomControl to Form and back and loosing it's state.

You should either try to pass the actual instance owned by Form to CustomControl without creating a new one or you could capture the state of the Panel in another object which you can pass to the constructor when you create a new Panel so that it is in the same state as the one you were dragging?

It seems as though you are trying to manually fire mouse events to compensate for problems in your design.

Always better to give some example code if you can than lengthy textual explanations.

Comment: It is necessary that the Panels in the CustomControl and the Form be two different Panels with slightly different appearance and controls. They have different This module has a few hundred lines - I could probably find a work-around by the time I trim it down for an example here.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this 
[Instant of custom control is disappear when click outside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922911/instant-of-custom-control-is-disappear-when-click-outside-it)

I have problem like you.
you shouldn't use a local variable for handling mouseEvent.
Try to use "Capture"  function. It's work for me.