# C# Passing controls around and maintaining events

Tags: c#, events, controls, mouseevent

Say I have a `Form` which we'll call it `ParentForm`, and it contains a `Panel` which we'll call `ContainerPanel`. Now, `ContainerPanel` contains a `Panel`, which we'll call `EntityPanel`.

So basically, the `Form` contains A `Panel` which contains a `Panel`.

In ContainerPanel, we have:

```
void EntityPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  ContainerPanel.Controls.Remove(EntityPanel);
  ParentForm.AcceptEntityPanel(EntityPanel);
}
```

and in MainForm, we have:

```
void AcceptEntityPanel(Panel panel)
{
  Controls.Add(panel);
  panel.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(
    delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Mouse has been released.");
    });
}
```

*Note: This is example code only, which I have just typed in here without verifying syntax, etc. I realise it is trivial to combine these two functions into one, however in my application these two functions do several other things and should be separate.*

So the `EntityPanel`, which belongs to `ContainerPanel` needs to be transferred to `ParentForm` when the user presses the mouse down.

When the user releases the mouse, I still need the `MouseUp` event to be triggered, but it is not working.

[Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671492/c-manually-triggered-mousedown-fails-to-trigger-mouseup), I was passing *information* about the panel and creating a new panel on the parent form, and manually calling the MouseDown method.

What I'm doing now, as you can see in my above example, is that I'm passing the *exact same* panel back to the parent form. I had hoped that this way the MouseDown/MouseUp would work, however it didn't.

I'm running out of ideas on how else to structure this module of my program.
Any ideas?

Comment: Just implement the EntityPanel.MouseUp or Click event instead and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks Hans, turns out the way I was doing it in the first place should have worked, but I was applying the handler to the wrong Panel (see my comment to Mark's answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
 void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    var innerPanel = new Panel();
    outerPanel.Controls.Add(innerPanel);

    innerPanel.MouseDown += (a,b) => 
     { 
       outerPanel.Controls.Remove(innerPanel);
       Controls.Add(innerPanel);
       innerPanel.MouseUp += (x,y) => MessageBox.Show("!");
     };
 }
```

Comment: AH-HA! I got it. Sorry - the issue was my fault. The panel contains sever Labels which describes the entity. the `Panel.MouseDown` will only work when the user clicks the white-space around the Labels, which is undesirable - so I overcame this by putting a transparent panel over the top of the whole contraption, allowing the user to click anywhere on the entity. The transparent panel captures MouseDown, but I was trying to catch MouseUp on Panel - which was the problem. Once I identified the problem, it is working exactly as expected.